# How to remove a stuck shower handle?

Tags: plumbing

I have a shower faucet "mixet" temperature handle that I can't remove. I have have the screw out but the knob won't come off. How do I get it off with out breaking, or pulling apart the pipes?

If it were plastic I'd just break it off. But it's metal and costs like $25.

Comment: Have you tried [Penetrating oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetrating_oil)?

Comment: Got an image to post?  That "may" help us determine what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

With things like that, I've found that putting a plastic bag full of white vinegar, warmed up a little is even better,  will dissolve various crud and free it up.  Seal it up with tape or a rubber band and leave it for a few hours or over night.

Answer (score 0):

I did three things:

1. As suggested by Marvin, I also used an acid to try to remove scale (CLR instead of vinegar). My shower design wasn't the mixet style, so I had to use a little plastic straw from a juice box with a bottle sprayer to get the liquid inside the shower handle (see purple arrow in the picture below).
2. I used a heat gun for a couple minutes on the shower handle to try to break the bond between the stuck metal parts.
3. I held the handle of an electric toothbrush up to the shower handle, also hoping that the vibrations would loosen stuck parts.

Not exactly sure which one(s) were key, but noting them all here in case they're helpful...

[image: shower handle with straw]